# Genetic Algorithm CrossOver

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I have a GA of population X.

After I run the gene and get the result for each gene I do some weighted multiply for the genes(so the better ranked genes get multiplied the most)

I get either x*2 or x*2+(x*100/10) genes. The 10% is random new genes it may or may not trigger depending on the mutation rate.

The problem is, I don' know what is the best approach to reduce the population to X again.

If the gene is a List should I just use list[::2] (or get every even index item from list)

What is a common practice when crossing genes?

**EDIT:**

Example of my GA with a population of 100;

- Run the the 100 genes in the fitness function and get the result. Current Population: 100
- Add 10% new random genes. Current Population:  110
- Duplicate top 10% genes. Current Population:  121
- Remove 10% worst genes. Current Population:  108
- Combine all possible genes(no duplicates). Current Population:  5778
- Remove genes from genepool until Population = 100. Current Population:  100
- Restart the fitness function

What I want to know is: How should I do the last step? Currently I have a list with 5778 items and I take one every '58' or expressed as len(list)/startpopulation-1

Or should I use a 'while True' with a  random.delete until len(list) == 100?

The new random genes should be added before or after the crossover?

Is there a way to make a gausian multiplication of the top-to-lowest rated items?

e.g: the top rated are multiplied by n, the second best by (n-1), the third by (n-2) ..., the worst rated multiplied by (n-n).

Comment: Can you drop the genes that had the lowest fitness on the previous iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not really know why you are performing GA like that, could you give some references?

In any case here goes my typical solution for implementing a functional GA method:

1. Run the the 100 genes in the fitness function and get the result.
2. Randomly choose 2 genes based on the normalized fitness function
   (consider this the probability of each gene to be chosen from the
   pool) and cross-over. Repeat this step until you have 90 new genes
   (45 times for this case). Save the top 5 without modification and
   duplicate. Total genes: 100.
3. For the 90 new genes and the 5 duplicates on the new pool allow
   them to mutate based on your mutation probability (typically 1%).
   Total genes: 100.
4. Repeat from 1) to 3) until convergence, or X number of
   iterations.

Note: You always want to keep unchanged the best genes such as you always get a better solution in each iteration.

Good luck!

Comment: I have no reference. I'm new to GA. I thought that this would yield a better weighted average.

But you putting this way seem a lot less computing.

How do you do the normalization of the fitness function?

Comment: @f.rodrigues After you calculate the fitness for each gene, sum all and divide each gene fitness by that [ f_gene=f_gene./sum(f_gene) ] The selection is called roulette-wheel selection.